# php array populate one dummy value with '0' based on the parent array

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my issue,

I have two arrays in php. One contains values with key and another for key reference.

```
Array
(
    [R8] => 1
    [R8-FF] => 3
)

Array
(
    [0] => R8
    [2] => R8-FF
    [3] => R9
    [4] => R10
)
```

All i need to populate another array based on the two arrays

Output array:

```
  Array
  (
    [R8] => 1
    [R8-FF] => 3
    [R9] => 0
    [R10] => 0
  )
```

I can do something with php foreach. But is there any short way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short solution with [array_fill_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-fill-keys.php) and [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-merge.php).

```
$a1 = ['R8' => 1, 'R8-FF' => 3];
$a2 = [0 => 'R8', 2 => 'R8-FF', 3 => 'R9', 4 => 'R10'];

$result = array_merge(array_fill_keys($a2,0),$a1);

var_dump($result);
//array(4) { ["R8"]=> int(1) ["R8-FF"]=> int(3) ["R9"]=> int(0) ["R10"]=> int(0) }
```